# Can one impose a coverage minimum for combined unit and integration tests?

Tags: scala, sbt, scoverage

When I run unit tests for my sbt project (with `sbt clean coverage test`), I get code coverage of ~77%.

When I run integration tests (`sbt clean coverage it:test`), I get code coverage of ~10%.

When I run both (`sbt clean coverage test it:test`), I get code coverage of ~84%.

I'd like to set an aggressive code coverage minimum and fail the build if it's not met, but if I add these build settings:

```
coverageMinimum := 83
coverageFailOnMinimum := true
```

...and then run `sbt clean coverage test it:test`, the coverage minimum is checked after the unit tests, before the integration tests can run, and the build fails:

```
[error] Coverage is below minimum [77.0% < 83.0%]
```

If I put `it:test` before `test`, it's even worse (`[10.0% < 83.0%]`).

Is there any way to stipulate that the 83% minimum should apply only after both unit and integration tests have run?  Or am I doomed to setting the coverage minimum meetable by my unit tests alone, and always remembering to put `test` before `it:test` on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic post-test coverage minimum check was removed in version 1.3.4 (see issue https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage/issues/132).

Upgrade plugin version to latest 1.3.5 and call `coverageReport` after all tests, e.g.:

`sbt clean coverage test it:test coverageReport`